# How stable are the Google NLP API Categories?

Tags: google-api, nlp, categories

We are considering using Google's 620 [Content Categories](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/categories) to organize some knowledge by category.  We would like to stay in sync with Google's categories, but we don't want to reorganize the knowledge should Google change these categories.

How stable are these categories?  Certainly, more subcategories and perhaps even more major categories could be added.  Does Google add to these?  Does Google ever remove a category, which seems less likely?

Comment: Well I don't understand what you mean by stability exactly but I have used them at work and they seem pretty handy. Obviously more subcategories could be added but then again if you want to just organize your knowledge then it is a good starting point. They are definitely a better option than Wikipedia because Wikipedia has some 5000 sub categories most of which are not useful e.g. Airports in Londons, Football Clubs in UK etc. Also the categories won't overlap much in results